# calculating the coefficients of a high-order polynomial having the roots

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, roots

I have 90 real and non-real roots and want to calculate the coefficients of the 90th degree polynomial that delivers these roots. I use procedures like "poly" in MATLAB but no matter how I try, the obtained polynomial does not give the intended roots. I think the very small round-off errors in the procedure of "poly" is to blame. Also, it must be something relating to ill-conditionedness.
Can you help me find the best solution? Thank you!

Comment: Why not use the form $p(x)=(x-r_1)(x-r_2)...(x-r_n)$. You can perform all operations on this form as the expanded form.

Comment: @NoChance I think in this way the round-off errors increase hugely! Think of the constant $r_1\times r_2\times...\times r_n$

Comment: I did not consider precision difference when I posted my comment. You must be aware of the many papers on the subject such as: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF03186531 and https://www-pequan.lip6.fr/~jmc/polycopies/Compensation-horner.pdf

Answer (score 2):

An alternative procedure to be tested : use iteratively **discrete convolution** operation (Matlab operator "conv") ; the coefficients of the resulting polynomial would be obtained in a list in the following way :

- initialize `P=[1]`
- for each real root $r_k$ do `P=conv(P,[1,-r_k])`
- for each pair of complex roots $a_k\pm ib_k$ do `P=conv(P,[1,-2a_k,a_k^2-b_k^2])`

**Explanations :**

- In the case of $2$ real roots like $3$ and $4$ :

$(x-3)(x-4)=x^2-7x+12 \leftrightarrow $ `conv([1,-3],[1,-4])=[1,-7,12]`

- in the case of 2 complex roots like $1+2i$ and $1-2i$, corresponding to polynomial $(x-1+2i)(x-1+2i)=1x^2-2x-3$, the coefficients of the product of this polynomial with, for example, $(x-4)$ will be given by `conv([1,-2,-3],[1,4])`

Comment: Thank you for your nice answer. I tried it but unfortunately for 90 roots the results are wrong. For example all my roots are negative, but the if I use the roots() for the obtained coefficients, positive roots appear! I test it for a set of 10 roots but it was correct. What is your idea on that?

Comment: Have you tested it on integer values ? The problem should be an **overflow** on the central coefficients around ranks 40 or 50 for a degree-90 polynomial, more than ill-conditioning (I can't, unfortunately, test it on Matlab today). For example the 45th coefficient of degree-90 polynomial $(x+2)^{90}$ is  $\approx 10^{43}$...

Comment: In fact, as Matlab computes the roots of a polynomial by computing the eigenvalues of its [companion matrix](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/roots.html) using the QR algorithm, it is maybe hard to track the exact reason of this disfunctionning...

Comment: No, my roots are real and complex numbers not integers. I will test the procedure for integers anyway to see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have had an idea, maybe sterile : as discrete convolution is connected with discrete Fourier Transform (operator Fast Fourier Transform : `fft`), it could be tested whether iterative multiplication of the fft  "components" could give the result (with a final `ifft` of course).